# Как сделать autoincrement id?

Tags: golang, mongodb

Пытаюсь сделать вот так:

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

type User struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId `bson:"id"`
    RefreshToken string `bson:"refresh_token"`
}


func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://127.0.0.1")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer session.Close()
    usersCollection := session.DB("usersdb").C("users")

    err = usersCollection.Insert(&User{RefreshToken: "test"})

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Но получаю ошибку: ObjectIDs must be exactly 12 bytes long (got 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо добавить тэг omitempty

```
type User struct {
    Id bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    RefreshToken string `bson:"refresh_token"`
}
```

BSON Object ID состоит из времени создания, хэш объекта, счетчика

> Returns a new ObjectId value. The 12-byte ObjectId value consists of:
>
> - a 4-byte timestamp value, representing the ObjectId’s creation,
>   measured in seconds since the Unix epoch
> - a 5-byte random value
> - a 3-byte incrementing counter, initialized to a random value

[источник](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)

Comment: Сработало, но при попытке получить его у меня достается запись с пустым id. Почему так?

Comment: не должно так быть. зависит как достаете.

Comment: Да тривиально вроде `usersCollection.Find(bson.M{}).One(&user)`

Comment: Ответьте пожалуйста... Я все записи выгрузил: `usersCollection.Find(bson.M{}).All(&users)`, но везде выводит `{ObjectIdHex("") test}`

Comment: Кажется я нашел решение. Почему-то надо Id в теге назвать как `_id`. Странно.

Comment: точно. я чет не обратил на это внимание. локально у меня работало))

Comment: _id - это специальный тэг в монго, который автоматически обозначает PK